# Why can't I sculpt on a plane I added a solidify modifier to?

Tags: sculpting

So, what I've done is to model a dagger using a plane. 
And to that plane I've added a solidify modifier, however, when I try sculpting it using one of my brushes it only turns into a disfigured piece of junk.

How can I solve this?

I saw a video from a few years back and it looks like that person is scaling the plane, but when I try the same thing it doesn't work (hence why I added the solidify modifier).

I'm a blender noob so don't be afraid to become too detailed in your answer.

Comment: Geometry created by Solidify won't be accessible for sculpting unless modifier is applied. If it isn't, you'll be basically sculpting just a plane. Please edit your post with more information about what didn't work for you with Multires / Subsurf modifiiers and include images of current object as well as desired result. Thanks.

Comment: Have you applied the solidify modifier? That could help.

Answer (score 5):

You have two options:

Option 1:
In sculpt mode, on the left tool shelf you need to enable "Dyntopo" the lower the number the more detailed your sculpt will be.

Option 2:
In the modifier panel add a subdivision surface to sub divide your plane so there are more faces to sculpt.

Hope that works.

Comment: I have tried both, not working at all I'm afraid!
Thanks for the answer though!

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy fix. Just change the axis from `x` `y` `z` in the sculpting menu. You can find that setting on the *Dyntopo Panel*.

Comment: Hello :). You can also add images to better illustrate the solution.